# Timer not working with infinite loop running

Tags: javascript

I am making a very basic node.js app for calculating primes, it uses a infinite loop to continuously calculate primes, I wanted to add a timecode to each prime number by using `setinterval` and a `time` variable, however the `setinterval` is not running, and I suspect it is because of the infinite loop, are there any fixes/alternatives? here is my code:

```
let isint = (num) => {
  if(num % 1 == 0 ) {
     return true
   } else {
    return false
   }
}

function numlength(num) {
  return num.toString().length
}

let time = 0
setInterval(() => time += 1, 1);


let primes = [2,3]

console.log(1)
console.log(2)
console.log(3)

function primecalc(primearray) {
  let isprime = true
  let NOP = 2
  for(let num = 3; num > 2 ;num += 2){
    isprime = true
    for(i of primearray) {
      if(isint(num / i) == true ) {
        isprime = false
      }
    }
    if( isprime == true) {
      NOP += 1
      primes.push(num)
      console.log(`prime:${num} number of primes:${NOP} number of 
      miliseconds:${time}`)
      if(numlength(num) > 10000) {
        return num
      }
    }
  }
}
```

primecalc(primes)

Comment: An infinite loop just doesn't work.

Comment: To add timecodes, use `Date.now()`. Not an interval that increments a counter.

Comment: The `setInterval` callback function will never be called because that can only happen when the call stack is empty, which never happens due to the busy loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of an infinite loop, consider placing your code in an interval with a small timeout. Loops halt execution and letting one run forever will not work out well for you. Additionally, as @Bergi noted, running `Date.now()` on each iteration of the interval will work out better than tracking a separate timer.

Comment: Since a prime calculation is intended to perform quickly, an interval driven routine is not the best approach as well. One could consider a worker thread continuously calculating and sending data to the main thread.

Comment: @Quasimodo'sclone Good point, I wasn't thinking about the fact that this is probably meant to run quickly. Simpy calling `Date.now()` in the console.log is most likely the best solution in that case.